# Anyone recognise this (probably text adventure) game?

Tags: game-identification

Can anyone recognise this game? I might be misremembering but when I saw this screenshot I remembered an old (probably text) adventure game or RPG that was started out in a space station. I ran the text through Google translate and it says:

> It looks like you're away

This was the first screen in the game and it was in English when I played it. I can't remember any other details though.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where did you find this image?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft it was reposted on some Tumblr recently, probably from there.

Comment: pinkerman's answer looks correct for this screenshot, but were you perhaps thinking of [Strange Odyssey](https://www.mobygames.com/game/strange-odyssey/screenshots)?

Comment: btw, I think the Japanese text says _"It seems like no one's home"_

Comment: Google translates 留守みたいだな to "It's like being away"; 留守 is the absence or "being away from home" with -みたい suffix meaning "-like". I don't know how to treat that な particle.

Comment: @Raj We may not be able to help the user track down the game they were originally thinking of, but it looks like [they're satisfied  with the anti-climatic ending](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/391094/anyone-recognise-this-probably-text-adventure-game#comment549734_391099), so I don't believe this fits our "No audiovisual artifact rule". aka an artifact was provided, the matching game was found, and it doesn't look like bonnici is looking for much else.

Comment: [/r/tipofmyjoystick](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/) may be able to assist you with tracking down the game you were originally thinking of.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I did some research using "MRTY" keyword and reverse image search, which leads to similar pixel art screenshots, with a girl named 奈美 (Nami).

Those images often refer to **Dragon City** (ドラゴンシティＸ指定) developed by Fairytail for MSX2 in 1991, [this one](https://www.generation-msx.nl/software/fairytale/dragon-city/1590/). The images on borders match.

[image]

However, other sources with a similar pixel art, and that girl named 奈美, point to [Game Technopolis](https://www.mobygames.com/company/game-technopolis):

> *Technopolis Soft* was the software label of publishing house Tokuma's computer gaming magazine Technopolis (known as "Tekupori" for short). After the Famicom became a big hit, the average Japanese games player quickly transitioned to consoles, leaving computers with more "adult" genres. Technopolis followed suite, and became more and more adult-oriented, to the point where they actually trademarked the term "bishōjo games". Their software department followed a similar path.
> The magazine ceased publishing in 1994, though the software label probably had disappeared before then.

So, this seems related to some adult-oriented games, and the (kind of) naked girl depicted on the sides of your screenshot makes me think it could be right.

Comment: Haha thanks, definitely not the game I was thinking of then.

Comment: I found [this page](https://kyber.io/orz/dragon-city) and [this page](https://vndb.org/v8850) (both NSFW!!) which confirm for certain that the game is Dragon City.  The first site indicates it was the [FM Towns Marty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_Towns_Marty) version _(a console released only in Japan)_, but according to [the Japanese wiki](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3X%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A) the game was never released for that console.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I found the first site, too, but my antivirus blocked the access and I didn't feel to open it anyway LOL